# opencart 1.5.6 404 Not Found when url in SEO-friendly URL

Tags: url, seo, opencart

my .htaccess works fine and also change in admin to use seo url then i can see the url change from

http://demo.cocabura.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=224

to

http://demo.cocabura.com/prod-white-pink-georgette-esha-deol-anarkali-suit-ws104

but getting 404 - File or directory not found. error

My .htaccess code as below :

```
# 1.To use URL Alias you need to be running apache with mod_rewrite enabled. 
# 2. In your opencart directory rename htaccess.txt to .htaccess.
# For any support issues please visit: http://www.opencart.com

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run   in ie. / becomes /shop/ 

RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L] 
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]


### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling any of the following settings, restore  the # as this means your host doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on.  This may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off

# 2. If your cart has magic quotes enabled, This may work to disable it:
# php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off

# 3. Set max upload file size. Most hosts will limit this and not allow it to be overridden but you  can try
# php_value upload_max_filesize 999M

# 4. set max post size. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields 
# php_value post_max_size 999M

# 5. set max time script can take. uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields
# php_value max_execution_time 200

# 6. set max time for input to be recieved. Uncomment this line if you have a lot of product options or are getting errors where forms are not saving all fields 
# php_value max_input_time 200

# 7. disable open_basedir limitations
# php_admin_value open_basedir none
```

and my opencart 1.5.6 comman/seo_url.php code :

```
<?php
  class ControllerCommonSeoUrl extends Controller {
public function index() {

    // Add rewrite to url class
    if ($this->config->get('config_seo_url')) {
        $this->url->addRewrite($this);
    }
    // Decode URL
    if (isset($this->request->get['_route_'])) {
        $parts = explode('/', $this->request->get['_route_']);
        foreach ($parts as $part) {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($part) . "'");

            if ($query->num_rows) {
                $url = explode('=', $query->row['query']);

                if ($url[0] == 'product_id') {
                    $this->request->get['product_id'] = $url[1];
                }

                if ($url[0] == 'category_id') {
                    if (!isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                        $this->request->get['path'] = $url[1];
                    } else {
                        $this->request->get['path'] .= '_' . $url[1];
                    }
                }   

                if ($url[0] == 'manufacturer_id') {
                    $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'] = $url[1];
                }

                if ($url[0] == 'information_id') {
                    $this->request->get['information_id'] = $url[1];
                }   
            } else {
                $this->request->get['route'] = 'error/not_found';   

            }
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
            $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/product';
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/category';
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
            $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/manufacturer/info';
        } elseif (isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
            $this->request->get['route'] = 'information/information';
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['route'])) {
            return $this->forward($this->request->get['route']);
        }
    }






}

public function rewrite($link) {
    $url_info = parse_url(str_replace('&amp;', '&', $link));

    $url = ''; 

    $data = array();

    parse_str($url_info['query'], $data);

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($data['route'])) {
            if (($data['route'] == 'product/product' && $key == 'product_id') || (($data['route'] == 'product/manufacturer/info' || $data['route'] == 'product/product') && $key == 'manufacturer_id') || ($data['route'] == 'information/information' && $key == 'information_id')) {
                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($key . '=' . (int)$value) . "'");

                if ($query->num_rows) {
                    $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];

                    unset($data[$key]);
                }                   
            } elseif ($key == 'path') {
                $categories = explode('_', $value);

                foreach ($categories as $category) {
                    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE `query` = 'category_id=" . (int)$category . "'");

                    if ($query->num_rows) {
                        $url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
                    }                           
                }

                unset($data[$key]);
            }
        }
    }

    if ($url) {
        unset($data['route']);

        $query = '';

        if ($data) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $query .= '&' . $key . '=' . $value;
            }

            if ($query) {
                $query = '?' . trim($query, '&');
            }
        }

        return $url_info['scheme'] . '://' . $url_info['host'] . (isset($url_info['port']) ? ':' . $url_info['port'] : '') . str_replace('/index.php', '', $url_info['path']) . $url . $query;
    } else {
        return $link;
    }

}
```

}
?>

Answer (score 0):

Their was not enough information provided to answer this question as their are many possible causes.  If your using Apache and you verified you have a working htaccess I would next check your errorlog for details as well as verifying id Apache Mod Rewrite is enabled.